# Integrate Laravel-4 authentication with Facebook or Tiwtter or Google Mail

Tags: php, laravel-4, registration

What are the best packages to integrate Laravel-4 to use for user authentication (registration and login) with Twitter or Facebook or Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used [artdarek/oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) for lots of different login providers (oauth1 and oauth2) and was very happy using it. the project itself also has good examples to get started with any login provider.

Comment: Amazing exactly what am looking for @zwacky, Thank you (: